# Build Menu from NavigableMap

Tags: grails, gsp

In a Grails 3.3 application, I'm trying to create a menu configuration and I'd like to use application.groovy for that.

*application.groovy:*

```
mainmenuconfig {
    menuitem_1 {
        id = 'menuitem-1'
        name='Home'
        sub=null
    }
    menuitem_2 {
        id ='menuitem-2'
        name='Stammdaten'
        sub = submenuitem_2 {
            menuitem_2_1 {
                id = 'menuitem-2-1'
                name ='Stamm-A'
                sub=null
            }
    }}
}
```

Retrieving the config via `grailsApplication.config.get('mainmenuconfig')` would give me the following:

```
[menuitem_1:[id:menuitem-1, name:Home, sub:null], menuitem_2:[id:menuitem-2, name:Stammdaten, submenuitem_2:[menuitem_2_1:[id:menuitem-2-1, name:Stamm-A]], sub:null]]
```

If I look at `getClass()` it says it's a `org.grails.config.NavigableMap`

Now, for my understanding, generating an `<UL> ... <LI>` tree should be done inside the View layer. For iterating through that structure, I will need recursion, because it can be n levels deep.

If I'm looking from `main.gsp`, I know the spot where I want to insert the menu tree, but how do I bring the data there and where do I do that recursion? Will I need a menu controller that is being called from the GSP? IMHO the GSP shouldn't do such calls. And on the other side, no controller should generate `<UL> ... <LI>` trees. I need the glue piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for an [interceptor](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors). You can have it add to your model after every action is finished. Then your view will have access to `menu` in its model and can build out the menu. It's fine to do recursion in your view if it's for display purposes.

```
class NavigationMenuInterceptor {

    NavigationMenuInterceptor() {
        matchAll()
    }

    boolean after() {
        model.menu = grailsApplication.config.getProperty('mainmenuconfig', Map)
        true
    }
}
```

To render your menu, you can use a template that recursively renders itself. Depending on your desired HTML output it might be something like below.

In the main body:

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${menu}" var="menuitem">
        <g:render template="menuitem" model="[menuitem: menuitem]"/>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

In your template `_menuitem.gsp`:

```
<li id="${menuitem.id}">
    ${menuitem.name}
</li>
<g:if test="${menuitem.sub}">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <g:render template="menuitem" model="[menuitem: menuitem.sub]"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea using an Interceptor, it seems exactly what I need, building the menu independently from all Controllers and Views. I've put my logic into the Interceptor so far, the menu could being generated. Works fine so far, except for one thing: WHERE shall the html snippet with the actual menu tree be generated? Shall I generate it inside the Interceptor and pass the string containing the snippet via params to the view? That would be a bit odd as regards MVC separation. On the other hand, I need recursion, that would be a bit odd to do in a GSP.

Comment: So far, I DID go the route creating the html snippet inside the Interceptor. It's working fine, I'm passing it over to the view by a params variable and in the GSP I have to show it in raw encoding using `${raw(params.menusnippet)}` so that html is properly rendered. As regards the religious question whether to allow that or not inside the Interceptor, I'm ready to adapt the solution, but for now I'm grateful for guiding me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I added a bit on recursively rendering a template that could be what you're looking for.